# update data with select2 not working what is missing?

Tags: jquery-select2

I have form:

```
        <form action="" id="update-loc-of-product">

    
            <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="" class="control-label">Nazwa części</label>
                      <select name="product_id" id="product_id" class="form-control select2">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <?php
                          $qry = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM products order by name asc");
                          while($row = $qry->fetch_assoc()):
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" <?php echo isset($product_id) && $product_id == $row['id'] ? 'selected' : '' ?>><?php echo ucwords($row['name']) ?></option>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    </div>



</form>
```

and 2 other select2 in form with lokalizacja and pudelko

Function in admin_class:

```js
function update-loc-of-prod(){
        extract($_POST);
        $save = $this->db->query("UPDATE products set lokalizacja = $lokalizacja, pudelko = $pudelko where id = $product_id");
        if($save)
            return 1;
}
```

This not working, what I do wrong please help me
I want to update data lokalizacja(location), pudelko(box) where is id of product (product_id)

I want to update data lokalizacja(location), pudelko(box) where is id of product (product_id)